# why does this NOT work for me? it always returns TRUE

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this seems to work for others but not me.

I have some data and in the Hours2 column there are clearly cells with NULL and some with hours like this

```
'9:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.'
NULL
NULL
'9:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.'
'9:00 a.m. - 5:00 p.m.'
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

yet I can't figure out how to do what seems like if should be a simple IF statement with some inline code. I already use

`<%# Eval("Hours2") %>` to get the values and that shows up fine...

IN the first case I want to display one or the other bit of text if Hours2 is NULL or not. (this is the label text for my hours one data, if there is Hours2 then Friday has a different time)

```
<%# Eval("Hours2") != DBNull.Value ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>
```

This based on answers from other on other things here at Stack sounds like it should work, but it's ALWAYS TRUE...

same thing if i'm trying to just use True or False to make things Visible or not...

```
Visible ='<%# Eval("Hours2") != DBNull.Value %>'
```

I'm clearly missing some thing here...!!!

Comment: Does `!(Eval("Hours2") is DBNull)` not work?

Comment: Have you tried `null` instead of `DBNull`? Depends highly on how you extract the data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried just null.  Have not had a chance to look into this code yet, but leppie your comment about how 'you extract the data' is good!  I didn't write the code feeding me the data from SQL, I better check what they did.

Comment: ok, I was sure I tried just `null` first thing and it didn't work, but after messing with `<%# GetString(Eval("Hours2")) %>` as suggested I was in fact getting a String or `null`

Comment: this works!  thanks!  `<%# Eval("Hours2") != null ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>`

Answer (score 2):

Move the logic to the codehind:

```
<%# GetString(Eval("Hours2")) %>
```

Then use your debugger to figure out what is actually being passed.

```
public string GetString(object hours){
 ...
}
```

Comment: this was a big help. Once I got debug to show me hours I could see it was evaluating and sending me a String "something" and `null`. I was sure I tested != null like first try, but it didn't work....

Comment: this worked!  thanks!  `<%# Eval("Hours2") != null ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>`   I should have tried it again must have had a typo i didn't see..!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Visible ='<%# Eval("Hours2").ToString() != "" %>'
```

or

```
Visible ='<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Hours2").ToString()) %>'
```

Comment: @leppie sorry brah, fixed it now

Comment: I've only really used `DBNull` in VB.Net, I've had better luck with `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` in C#

Comment: I want to downvote again. The code is still bogus and wont compile. The result of `DataBinder.Eval` is `object`, not `string`.

Comment: CS1525: Invalid expression term '>'

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking it a different way... this is how I might do it.

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Hours2").ToString()) ? "mon-thurs" : "mon-fri")%>
```

Comment: If `Eval("Hours2)` returns something that doesn't implement a custom `ToString` this too will always be `true`

Answer (score 0):

how you can get it from SQL. Means using LINQ or call SP? You can use isnull(Hours2,0) Hours2 or isnull(Hours2,'') Hours2 in your Query. and it will work for you like this.

```
<%# Eval("Hours2") != 0 ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>
```

OR

```
<%# Eval("Hours2") != '' ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>
```

OR

```
<%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Hours2").ToString()) ? "mon - thurs" : "mon - fri" %>
```